# htaccess rewrite rule for different environments

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

On our staging server there are different versions of an PHP application. Each version in a different folder, so that the PM can approve feature by feature. The strucure looks like this:

`- docroot
  - origin
    - develop
  - origin
    - feature
      - feature_1`

The URLs look like this:

`- http://dev.example.com/project/origin/develop
- http://dev.example.com/project/origin/feature/feature_1/`

Local development looks like this:
`http://project.local/`

Now i want to rewrite URLs.

`http://project.local/foo/example1/example2`

should move to

`http://project.local/bar/example1/example2`

I tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} foo/(.*)
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)?$ /bar/$1 [R=302,L]
```

which works as expected on local environment.
On staging server it redirects from:
`http://dev.example.com/project/origin/develop/foo/example1/example2`

to:

`http://dev.example.com/bar/example1/example2`

which doesn't work.
Is there a way to handle this on local & staging environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that on staging server you are keeping this rule in a .htaccess inside `/project/origin/develop` instead of site root .htaccess.

You can use this generic rule that will work in both the places:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*/)?foo/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1bar/%2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you, @anubhava

Comment: Tweaked a bit to avoid double slash in new redirected URL.